# Need syntax to write a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I have written an application to manage my home library. It has a table for Books and a table for Works and a many to many table to link them. Each Book can contain multiple Works and each Work can appear in multiple Books. Each of Books and Works has a Title.
I want a query that returns a list of ID and Title for all those Books that has an (input) string contained in the Book Title or Work Title.
Current implementation gives two or more entries if Book contains two or more Works that contain the string. I assume I have to Group but can't get the syntax right.

Currently setting the rowsource for the list on an Access form to be:

```
SELECT QBW.ID, QBW.Title, QBW.WorkTitle
  FROM qryBookOrWork AS QBW
 WHERE ((QBW.Title LIKE 'civil') OR (QBW.WorkTitle LIKE 'civil'))
```

Don't know how to Group (if that is required)

This produces two copies of Uncivil Wars because that book contains two Works (and the Book contains the string 'civil') giving two rows in QBW.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_grouping_data.htm

Answer (score 0):

After writing this I had the thought that I could 'wrap' the current query in a "SELECT DISTINCT QBW.ID, QBW.Title FROM (    )"

and it seems to work!